# Need ideas to handle combobox in grid for imported data if name/id is inaccurate/unavailable

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, mvvm

We have a form that includes a lot of data but specifically an employee name and id. This data will be entered through a grid control. The employee id will be read-only while the user will have a combo box to select or type in the employee's name.

That's easy enough but we are importing the data and using WPF and MVVM. Because we are importing the data we cannot guarantee that the employee data will contain an employee id (this may be a new employee not setup in the system). **[Requirement1]:** This means that the ComboBox for the employee name has to have the ability to show the name even if it's not in the ItemsSource list of the combo box which is something that I have already solved.

**[Requirement2]:** That said, the problem I have is that if I select a valid name from the list I want the employee id to auto magically be completed based on my selection. If I want to do this in the view model then I have to possibly set up my EmployeeName property as a KeyValuePair instead of a string (which it is now) which will not allow me to do Requirement1. Correct? Having it as a KeyValuePair or whatever structure will allow me to retrieve the EmployeeId from the structure and place it in the EmployeeId property.

How can I achieve both requirements while still using a combobox and grid?

Comment: give new Employee a false ID (of, say, -1)?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to approach this in one of two ways:

1) Bind the list of employee names to the combobox, then, when it is needed, get the employee id from the database (or whereever it is stored). I'm not a big fan of this approach.

2) Create a small class to hold the Employee Name and Id, then create a collection (list, dictionary) of this class and bind it to the combobox. Prior to binding, if the specified employee name does not exist in the list of employees, insert a new instance of the class into the list with the name and a dummy version of the employee id (0, -1). You can then bind the appropriate properties of the Combo (DisplayMember, ValueMember) to the appropriate properties in your class.

Comment: #2 sounds good to me - but why a class and not KeyValuePair or Tuple?

Comment: @sq33G: I always create a class even if I don't think I need it at the moment because inevitably I'll find that it is needed down the road. For example, if the requirement for the combobox is extended at some point to require 2 or 3 more columns (dept, manager, status, for example), then it is much easier to handle the addition in a class rather than having to replace all keyvalue pair instances with tuples, and then all tuples with classes. Now, if it was a non-business object type of entity (i.e. a lookup list of cities, or genders), then I would definitely consider a different approach.